# Pact: How to deploy a new Provider version when the Consumer has updated it's contract, when using "can-i-deploy"?

Tags: pact

Let's say we have the following verification matrix in the Pact broker:

| Consumer version | Provider version | Verified? | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 (Production) | 1 (Production) | yes |  |
| 2 | 1 | no | Consumer updated the contract |
| 2 | 2 | yes | Provider is updated according to contract |

We use "can-i-deploy" to check whether we can deploy a version to Production. How can we ever deploy either Consumer v2 or Provider v2 in this case? The "can-i-deploy" script would prevent us from doing it, because there is no verified contract on Production.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading this guide for the recommended CI/CD setup: https://docs.pact.io/pact_nirvana, and specifically, this [guide](https://docs.pact.io/provider/recommended_configuration) for the recommended selectors.

The short answer, is that version 2 of the provider would verify more than one contract - usually, you would want to test that provider won't break what's currently in production (using the `deployedOrReleased` selector) *and* make sure you're compatible with the latest dev branch (usually via `mainBranch: true`).

This way, the provider can release without breaking what's in prod and also won't break the consumer that's about to release.